# System of ODEs: adding initial conditions and taking limit of the solution

Tags: differential-equations

I have a system of ODEs for the functions `w1,m1,w2,m2`.
*Mathematica* solves the system, but I am not able to add initial conditions. Moreover, I need the asymptotic solution, for time going to infinity, but I am not able to get it.

My code is :

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = {w1*c*(Nss - w1 - δ*m1) + γ*(w2 - w1), 
  c*m1*(Nss - w1 - δ*m1) + γ*(m2 - m1), 
  w2*c*(Nss - w2 - δ*m2) + γ*(w1 - w2), 
  c*m2*(Nss - w2 - δ*m2) + γ*(m1 - m2)}
b = {w1, m1, w2, m2}
J = D[a, {b}]
J2 = J /. {w2 -> w1, m2 -> m1}
M = J2 /. Nss -> w1 + δ*m1
B = M /. {w1 -> w0, m1 -> m0}
X[t_] = {w1[t], m1[t], w2[t], m2[t]};
system = X'[t] == B.X[t];
sol = DSolve[system, {w1, m1, w2, m2}, t]
```

I have tried following online documentation, to add initial conditions and taking 
`Limit[sol, t->Infinity]`, but nothing seems to work.
I suppose I have to specify the signs of the parameters, also?

Comment: What are the initial conditions? Shouldn't `w1,w2,m1,m2` depend on `t` in `a`? (i.e., `w1`$\to$`w1[t]`, etc.)

Comment: What is the system of ODEs you're trying to solve?  Is it `a` (with corresponding derivative added)?  That looks like a two-species, two-patch Lotka-Volterra competition model.  Otherwise, what's the meaning behind the steps between `a` and `B`?

Comment: Derivatives vanish in steady state.  So, if `sol` approaches a steady state as `t` approaches infinity, the steady state can be obtained from `B.X == 0`.

Comment: The initial conditions are w1=w0+1; w2=w0; m1=m2=m0; I want to see what happens when the system starts one unity away (in w1) from the steady state.

Comment: The system I am tryng to solve is a, linearized, with corresponding derivative added, evaluated in the steady state. The steady state is given by w1=w2, m1=m2, Nss = w1 - δ*m1, Nss = w2 - δ*m2. The meaning of those steps is to calculate the Jacobian and evaluate it on the steady state line.                                     
                                                                                                                  
Yes,  it is a two-species, two-patch L-V Model. Do you know where I can find more about that ? Got only one article which doesn't seem to do the job.